# What's the difference between Node.js HTTP request and get?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

What's the difference between Node.js HTTP request and get?

(and when to use which)

Docs: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the exact docs you linked:

> Since most requests are GET requests without bodies, Node.js provides this convenience method. The only difference between this method and `http.request()` is that it sets the method to GET and calls `req.end()` automatically.